# TypoScript: mixed menu of public and access restricted pages

Tags: menu, typo3, menuitem, typoscript

I want to make a menu containing both public and access restricted pages, based on the following requirements:

1. public pages should be linked, regardless whether the user is logged in or not
2. access restricted pages should not be linked if the user is not logged in
3. access restricted pages should be linked if the user is logged in

This is what I have so far:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu.1 = TMENU
lib.menu.1 {
    // Satisfies requirement 2
    NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
    // Satisfies requirement 3
    USR = 1
}
```

However, as you would expect, requirement 1 isn't satisfied this way. I can't come up with a way to make `lib.menu.1.NO` conditional based on the page being public or access restricted.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `NO.doNotLinkIt = 1` then all *normal* pages are not linked. Actually you want to set `showAccessRestrictedPages = <uid>` where the `uid` is the ID if your page with the login form. [See documentation.](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonProperties/Index.html) You can set `CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1`, for requirement 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will also make access restricted page visible irrespective of login status

```
menu.right.3 = TMENU
menu.right.3.wrap = <ul>|</li></ul></li>
menu.right.3 {
   expAll = 0
   NO.ATagTitle.field = title
   NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>

   ACT = 1
   ACT.ATagTitle.field = title
   ACT.allWrap = <li class="active">|

   showAccessRestrictedPages = <login page uid>
   showAccessRestrictedPages.addParams = 
&return_url=###RETURN_URL###&pageId=###PAGE_ID###

}
```